# soundcloud api php add follower

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I am making a page where you can log in with your soundcloud and gain access to download my songs as long as you are following me on soundcloud. I have authentication working but cannot figure out the following part. I pretty much copied and pasted the examples from the soundcloud developers website under the like and follow section, and it seams neither is working how its supposed to. The try catch makes it appear that i am not following my main account (which i got the user id# from testing the authentication step) even if i go on soundcloud, on my test account and follow my main account. Here is the error I am getting:

```
Warning:  Missing argument 2 for Services_Soundcloud::put(), called in /my_website/index.php on line 43 and defined in /my_website/Services/Soundcloud.php on line 636



Notice:  Undefined variable: postData in /my_website/Services/Soundcloud.php on line 642



Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 404.' in /my_website/Services/Soundcloud.php:941
Stack trace:
#0 /my_website/Services/Soundcloud.php(645): Services_Soundcloud->_request('https://api.sou...', Array)
#1 /my_website/index.php(43): Services_Soundcloud->put('/me/followings/...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in my_website/Services/Soundcloud.php on line 941
```

heres the code im running:

```
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';
//session_destroy();
session_start();

$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud(client_id, secret_id, redirect_uri)
$authURL = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();

echo "<pre>";

if (!empty ($_SESSION['token'])){
        $soundcloud->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
} else if(!empty($_GET['code'])){
        try{
                $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
                $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['access_token'];
                $soundcloud->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
                exit($e->getMessage());
        }
} else {
        echo "<a href='".$authURL."'><img border='0' alt='Connect with Soundcloud' src='connect.png'></a>";
}

if (!empty ($_SESSION['token'])){
        // check the status of the relationship
        echo $_SESSION['token'];
        try {
                $soundcloud->get('/me/followings/#######');
        } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
                if ($e->getHttpCode() == '404')
                        print "You are not following user #######\nTrying to follow now\n";
                        $soundcloud->put('/me/followings/#######');
        }
}
```

Are the examples on soundcloud wrong or am i doing something wrong before i get to those commands?

also please note that my soundcloud object init and followings/##### was changed to protect my information.

Comment: you should check your postData variable in soundcloud, something is wrong with your put command. Btw. I'm actively maintaining a more object oriented library to work with soundcloud have you tried it? http://www.github.com/njasm/soundcloud

Comment: sorry for not seeing this till i found the answer.... and for having two accounts. I will definately keep your library in mind when I eventually run into another problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of research and trial and error if figured out that setting the path to:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/me/followings/#######?oauth_token=MY_TOKEN
```

seems to work. I don't know if this is just a workaround or how the API was intended to be used but its the only way i could get it to work, i was assuming the soundcloud client object was sending the token automatically with the command but it appears not.

I have also figured out that if it does find a match (user is following the id number) then it returns a 303 error, which the api guide does not even list in their http error codes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slash in front of `me` which must not be there. The following works for me:

```
$soundcloud->put('me/followings/#########','',array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xml')));
```